# In Xorg fontconfig, why two font caches, /var/cache and $HOME? Possible to get rid of the latter?

Tags: linux, fonts, xorg, fontconfig

In Xorg fontconfig, there're (at least) two fontcaches, by default `/var/cache/fontconfig` and `~/.fontconfig`, defined in `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`.

Q1. But what's the rationale? Only one, the system wide one suffices, no? In my case, there're 69 files in `~/.fontconfig`, and 24 of them have identical copies also in `/var/cache/fontconfig`.

Q2. Is it possible to get rid of `~/.fontconfig`? `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` is not for writing your personal configuration.

(Q3. Why does X do all as the user root? It should be user X, right? Caches are made by root!)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because users can install their own fonts and their own configuration in other directories and don't have permission to write caches for them to the system `/var/cache` directory.

(fontconfig isn't actually part of X, but a system that sits alongside X to replace the
X11 font system with a more modern one that many modern desktop programs use instead of X fonts.)

Comment: Probably you're right, but all caches in my `~/.fontconfig` are for fonts in `/usr/share/fonts`. This design does not seem reasonable at all. (Many duplicates will exist if there're many users.)

Comment: You should only end up with caches in ~/.fontconfig for system fonts when the system font caches for those fonts are missing or out-of-date.